# Convert BMP to TIFF using System.Drawing.Common on Mac OS X

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, tiff, bmp

I'm trying to convert a BMP image to a tiff image using `System.Drawing.Common` with the following C# code (.NET CORE 3.1) on Mac os:

```cs
        public void SaveBitmapAsTiff(string location, Bitmap image)
        {

            var imageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
            var encoder = Encoder.Compression;
            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            
            var encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(
                encoder,
                (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
            location = location.Replace(".bmp", "");
            image.Save(location + ".tiff", imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
            // image.Save(location + ".tiff", ImageFormat.Tiff); Also tried this method overload
        }
        
        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
        {
            int j;
            ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
            encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            for(j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
            {
                if(encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                    return encoders[j];
            }
            return null;
        }
```

the `location` parameter contains the file path we want to write to, and the `image` parameter contains the bitmap we loaded from the disk.

When I try to run this code I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented.
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.CheckStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at BmpTiffConverter.Services.FileService.SaveBitmapAsTiff(String location, Bitmap image) in /Users/tomcoldenhoff/Documents/ReSoftware/Repositories/BmpTiffConverter/BmpTiffConverter/Services/FileService.cs:line 54
   at BmpTiffConverter.Services.ConverterService.ConvertBmpToTiff(String inputPath, String outputPath) in /Users/tomcoldenhoff/Documents/ReSoftware/Repositories/BmpTiffConverter/BmpTiffConverter/Services/ConverterService.cs:line 20
```

My google searches suggested that I had to install libgdiplus which I already did with `brew install mono-libgdiplus` and `brew upgrade mono-libgdiplus`.

I've also tried @Andy's suggested answer by installing the `runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing` package, unfortunately this didn't work.

Does anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: Which dotnet core veresion are you using?

Comment: @TreviAwater I'm using 3.1, I've edited the post as well

Comment: I can call Save successfully but not SaveAdd for multiple frames... I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This question helped me solve the error `the type initializer for 'gdip' threw an exception`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `mono-libgdiplus` doesn't implement `EncoderValue.CompressionLZW` encoder parameter. I would suggest not using that library, and instead install this nuget package:

[image: mac os libgdiplus]

`runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing`

Once I added that package, your code worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi @Andy, Thank you for your response. I've tried installing the by you suggested NuGet package, unfortunately the exception remains.

Comment: @TomColdenhoff -- i would start a new project and try it. I tested it on my mac and it worked with no issues.

Comment: Creating a new project didn't solve the problem, maybe it's an issue with my Mac device because you said it worked on your machine. I'll try it on another Mac device later today and keep you updated.

Comment: ran it on a different Mac machine and it worked. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have a Mac to test. I tested your code on Windows and Ubuntu 20 with DotNet Core 3.1 and your code seems to work. I can only guess it is something to do with how you create or modify your `Bitmap` potentially.

Below is how I created the project under Linux. `dotnet add package` is how I added the `System.Drawing.Common` NuGet package. I'm not sure how it works on Mono or if you are using Mono.

```
> dotnet new console
> dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common
> dotnet restore
```

I edited program.cs

```
> dotnet build
> dotnet run
```

and it ran perfectly fine. I can now open the tiff image in any image viewer.

From a code style point of view there are quite a few changes I would recommend. I know you followed MSDN's code examples, but as it stands their examples are not very clear in this instance. I've just copied and pasted my whole .cs file and added comments to the various modifications. Writing clear code is just as important as writing working code.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    // made the function more generic Bitmap inherits from Image and Image contains
    // the save feature so it might as well be made more general
    public static void SaveImageAsTiff(string location, Image image)
    {
        // fetch tiffCodec
        var tiffCodec = ImageCodecInfo
            .GetImageEncoders()
            .Where(info => info.MimeType == "image/tiff")
            .First();

        // create encoderParameters
        // this structure is much clearer IMO
        // (Can you see that there is now a color depth parameter?)
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(2) 
        {
            Param = new EncoderParameter[]{
                new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW),
                new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 24L)
            }
        };

        // save image using codec and encoder parameters
        // it is common behavior to just save the file with the given location parameter 
        // and not to try do some extension conversion
        image.Save(location, tiffCodec, encoderParameters);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // original bitmap location
        // (Yes forward slashes work on Windows so relative file paths are simple to handle)
        string bmpLocation = @"C:/Images/test.bmp";
        //string bmpLocation = @"~/Images/test.bmp"; // test on Linux

        // tidy way to convert file extensions of a path in C#
        string tiffLocation = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(bmpLocation, "tiff");

        // open image and force it to be a bitmap for examples sakes
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(bmpLocation));

        // save image as tiff
        SaveImageAsTiff(tiffLocation, bmpImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kwiksilver, thank you for your response. Unfortunately, your answer didn't work for me.